# JS calculate differents width and height for each refresh of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've some issues with width and height of an element with JavaScript.

Here is what I want to have :[image]

Here is the result one in the ten refreshes of the page. The other time, here is what i have :

[image]

I'm not changing my window size, nothing. Just refreshing the page.

Here is my code piece in JS :

```
    const wi = box[0].offsetWidth;
    const he = box[0].offsetHeight;
    
    for (let h = 0; h < vclimgs.length; h++) {
        let itemm = vclimgs[h];
        itemm.style.width = "calc(" + wi + "px - 30%)";
        itemm.style.height = "calc(" + he + "px - 40%)";
        console.log(he)
        console.log(itemm.height)
    }
```

Here is my CSS code, for .vclBox (where box[0] comes from) and .vehicleSelector who is the main div (parent of .vclBox)

```
.vehicleSelector {
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    padding-top: 2%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
    gap: 10%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.vclBox {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #374149;
}
```

Do you have an idea of the problem ?

I tried to log the size of each vehicle images and obtain this. Lines 1, 3, 5, ... are for values of "he". Lines 2, 4, 6, ... are for values of each vehicle images.

921
554
921
554
921
582
921
542
921
617

Comment: Try making an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in something like [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/). As it is right now it's unclear how to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Read into **responsive web design** which is the actual issue. A good start to solving the issue would be not to use hardcoded sizes in pixels but relative units.

Comment: Are waiting for your images to finish loading before you run your js?  Also why do you need js to do this?